# High-Dimensional Balls

Tags: geometry

[High-Dimensional Balls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vr19S.png)

[Equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EFGc.png)

Hi,

I don't quite understand exactly what the equation describes. Somehow it seems familiar and I thought it might be the divergence theorem, but unfortunately divergence does not occur.

If I understand it correctly, the function on the left is integrated over the entire sphere. On the right side again the function and its value at distance R over the surface of the sphere.

If I understood it correctly, what the two side mean, I do not understand unfortunately however, why this works?

Comment: Please put the important parts of your question in Mathjax/Latex. It's one of the basic requirements of the site.

Comment: Thanks also Jaap Scherphuis for your explanation.

 
JonathanZ supports MonicaC I will make sure to use latex next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what it is saying is that if you have an integral of the form
$$\int_{\mathbb B(0,R)}f(|\boldsymbol x|)\mathrm d^n\boldsymbol x$$
That when you rewrite the integral using polar coordinates you get
$$\int_{\mathbb B(0,R)}f(|\boldsymbol x|)\mathrm d^n \boldsymbol x=\int_{0}^R \int_0^{2\pi}\underbrace{\int_0^\pi\cdots\int_0^\pi}_{n-2~\text{of these}}f(r) r^{n-1}~\{\text{angular terms}\}\mathrm d\theta_1\dots\mathrm d\theta_{n-1} \\ =\int_0^R f(r)r^{n-1}\mathrm dr\cdot\{\text{angular integral}\}$$
The angular integral turns out to evaluate to the surface area of the unit sphere. And since $O_n(r)=r^{n-1}\cdot\{\text{surface area of unit sphere}\}$ you get
$$\int_{\mathbb B(0,R)}f(|\boldsymbol x|)\mathrm d^n\boldsymbol x=\int_0^R f(r)O_n(r)\mathrm dr$$

Comment: Thanks K.defaoite for your explanation, now I get it :-)